# How can I get one image to appear at a time based on a condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, conditional-statements

my webpage is doing what it's supposed to do however, I want the resulted image to disappear once the button is clicked on again. What it currently does, is it leaves the image from the last result and just shows the image from the next result which makes it confusing, it basically just piles on the images. I want only one image to appear, one at a time. Please help!

this is what is happening:
[image: current display]

this is what I want to happen (one image at a time):
[image]

HTML:

```
<form>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="firstDegree">First Degree:</label>
                <input type="number" id="firstDegree">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="secondDegree">Second Degree:</label>
                <input type="number" id="secondDegree">
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="missingAngle();">Enter</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <h2 id="result"></h2>
    <img src="images/acute-triangle.png" id="acute-triangle" style="display:none;">
    <img src="images/right-triangle.png" id="right-triangle" style="display:none;">
    <img src="images/obtuse-triangle.png" id="obtuse-triangle" style="display:none;">
```

JS:

```
function missingAngle(firstDegree, secondDegree) {
    var firstDegree = parseInt(document.getElementById('firstDegree').value);
    var secondDegree = parseInt(document.getElementById('secondDegree').value);

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
        (firstDegree + secondDegree > 180) ? 'Sorry, not a triangle.' :
        (firstDegree + secondDegree > 90) ? 'The missing angle is an acute angle.' :
        (firstDegree + secondDegree === 90) ? 'The missing angle is a right angle.' :
        (firstDegree + secondDegree < 90) ? 'The missing angle is an obtuse angle.' :
        null;
    event.preventDefault();

    if (firstDegree + secondDegree > 90) {
        document.getElementById('acute-triangle').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (firstDegree + secondDegree === 90) {
        document.getElementById('right-triangle').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (firstDegree + secondDegree < 90) {
        document.getElementById('obtuse-triangle').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the display to none for the other two images when you set the display to block for the image that should be shown?  If you add a class to all three images, you could simply set display to none for all images using that class, and then show the image you want.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the situation. Can you please provide more relevant photos?

Comment: @devlincarnate yeah, that's what I want to do now (create a class) because now my code is long and repetitive. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that you show the image but latter you don't make dissapear it. Try this:

```
document.getElementById('right-triangle').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('obtuse-triangle').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('acute-triangle').style.display = 'none';
```

First I set all to dysplay:none; later you only have to display one:

```
document.getElementById('right-triangle').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('obtuse-triangle').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('acute-triangle').style.display = 'none';
if (firstDegree + secondDegree > 90) {
document.getElementById('acute-triangle').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Yes! this worked, thanks a lot! Do you have any ideas on how to simplify the code? because it's really long and repetitive now. Thanks